# Why is $\mathcal R=\{B\cup(C|A):B\in \sigma_{\mathcal R}(A\cap \mathcal G),C\in \sigma_{\mathcal R}(\mathcal G)\}$ a $\sigma$-Ring?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

One of the remarks in our textbook says it is very trivial to show that $\mathcal R=\{B\cup(C|A):B\in \sigma_{\mathcal R}(A\cap \mathcal G),C\in \sigma_{\mathcal R}(\mathcal  G)\}$ is a $\sigma$-ring, where $\mathcal  G$ is a family of subsets of a set $\Omega$ and $A\subset \Omega$.

I know that I need to show that

$(B_1\cup(C_1|A))|(B_2\cup(C_2|A))\in \mathcal R$

and

$\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n\cup(C_n|A)\in \mathcal R$

but I can't figure how. It there a way to show this?

Comment: What are $B_n$ and $C_n$? Also, I am not sure this is a sigma ring.

Comment: @Isaac, why not!?